# .replace() in a DataFrame does not replace

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove `;` from a column in a DataFrame, but when I use the `.replace(';', ' ')` method it does not replace the semicolumn, here is how i am doing it:

```
for i in excel_file['dateTime']:
    i.replace(';', ' ')
```

This is how my `'dateTime'` column looks like:

```
11-06-18;
18-06-18;
18-09-18;
14-06-18;
20-06-18;
13-06-18;
21-06-18;
19-06-18;
19-06-18;
20-06-18;
11-06-18;
22-06-18;
```

Comment: maybe it's easier to delete the last character? `i = i[:-1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `for` loops.  Instead:

```
excel_file['dateTime'] = excel_file['dateTime'].str.replace(';', ' ')
```

Implicit in this answer is the fact that `str.replace()` returns a new string, rather than modifying the original in-place.  That was the functional defect in your original code.  But doing it without a `for` loop will be many times faster.

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.replace(';', ' ')` on some string - it will **return** new string with replacement.
So you need:

```
for i in excel_file['dateTime']:
    excel_file['dateTime'][i] = i.replace(';', ' ')  # probably
```

That's if you need replace. But also @john-zwinck suggested better solution for your case